# Linear transformations in infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

If we look at an $n$ - dimensional vector space $V$ and a linear transformation 
\begin{equation}
T : V \to V, \quad x \mapsto Tx \quad \forall \, x \in V
\end{equation}
then given a choice of basis for $V$ one can represent $T$ in terms of a $n \times n$ matrix $A_T = A_T(i,j)$

Is this also the case for linear transformations on infinite - dimensional vector spaces, where we replace the matrix $A_T$ by an integral ?

In particular, since differentiation is a linear map, that would mean differentiation can be written in the form of an integral ... I realize this is either a dumb question (because it is obviously wrong) or it is some classic result I haven't found yet. In both cases it would be great to get some reference where I can learn more about it, many thanks!

Comment: This topic http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483/matrix-of-infinite-dimension may interest you.

Comment: In general, no.  Not every linear transformation is described by an integral kernel.  Many important linear transformations are, but also many important linear transformations are not.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo thanks, exactly what I was asking, I searched for a similar question before posting this but didn't find it - I guess I have to refine the tags I use when I do a search :)

Comment: @GEdgar ok that sounds interesting, it shows I have to dig deeper. Many thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The axiom of choice is equivalent to the assertion that any vector space (no matter how large) has a basis. Given a choice of basis of an arbitrary vector space $V$, one can represent a linear transformation $T : V \to V$ using an infinite row-finite matrix (this means that only finitely many entries in each row are nonzero).

However, in practice this is not useful, since most infinite-dimensional vector spaces (such as the space of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$, for example) are *huge* and don't have reasonable bases. To study these, we instead introduce a [topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space), and then we do [functional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis) instead of linear algebra.

Three additional comments:

- In most contexts, the easiest way to describe differentiation is as differentiation.
- However, in [complex analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis), differentiation actually **is** an integral, thanks to the [Cauchy integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).
- For some $V$ one can talk about [integral operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) which on the one hand are a useful generalization of matrices but on the other hand do not represent all operators one might care about. In the examples I know about, integral operators are [compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator), for example, and differentiation usually is not; it's generally not even [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator)!

Comment: this is a really great answer, thanks very much for sharing your insight!

Comment: About the linear transformation can be presented as an infinite row-finite matrix, which reference I can read ? Seemly, the proof is not obvious.  Thanks.